# Powershell and ColdFusion update active directory with different server

Tags: powershell, coldfusion

I am just learning about Powershell. I want to try and update data in AD, but my AD Server and Powershell are on different servers.

For example, my AD server is 111.111.111.111 and my Powershell.exe is on server 222.222.222.222. I am using ColdFusion programming to execute my Powershell script.

Here is my ColdFusion script :

```
<cfoutput>
<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
           arguments="C:\Users\Public\Documents\ADtest.ps1" />
</cfoutput>
```

Here is my Powershell script ADtest.ps1 :

```
$userID = "11111"
$password = "p@ssw0rd"
$ADuser =  Get-ADUser $userID 
If($ADuser) 
{ 
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $userID 
    Set-adaccountpassword $userID -reset -newpassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force) 
    Set-aduser $userID -changepasswordatlogon $true 
}
```

Is it possible to execute a powershell script to update AD (Active directory) data on a different server?

Comment: I  know you're learning PowerShell, but if the ultimate goal is to use ColdFusion to manage an AD server, it would be much easier using the `cfldap` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Most Powershell AD Commands use the parameter -Server for specifying the target DC:

```
    Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Server $DC
```

Having said that Powershell usually does not switch DCs during the execution of the script.

Hope that helps -tom